# estou tentando deixar minhas imagens em 2 colunas empilhadas uma em cima da outra, porem ficam apenas em uma coluna e nao consigo sair de onde parei

Tags: html, css

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.app {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.app header {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 20vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background: rgb(194, 122, 239);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(194, 122, 239, 1) 15%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 93%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(194, 122, 239, 1) 15%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 93%);
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(194, 122, 239, 1) 15%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 93%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#c27aef", endColorstr="#ffffff", GradientType=1);
}


/* HEADER */

.app header div {
  width: 55%;
}


/* Div da esquerda */

.app header div:nth-child(1) {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  position: relative;
}


/* Div do centro */

.app header div:nth-child(2) {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-direction: column;
}


/* Div da direita */

.app header div:nth-child(3) {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.logo {
  width: 130px;
  margin-right: 40px;
}


/* SEARCHBAR */

div.searchbar {
  background-color: #fff;
  height: fit-content !important;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 50% !important;
  min-width: 300px;
}

div.searchbar input {
  outline: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0;
  width: 90%;
}


/* Nav bar */

a.link {
  margin-top: 10px;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 30px 10px;
}


/* Icones */

.icones {
  margin: 0 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

div.container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.bolso {
  width: 130px;
}

.kel {
  width: 130px;
}

.julio {
  width: 130px;
}

.deus {
  width: 130px;
}

.sabri {
  width: 130px;
}

.yuri {
  width: 130px;
}

.mirian {
  width: 130px;
}

.naro {
  width: 130px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link href="./css/estile.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <title>Minds</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="app">
    <header>
      <div>
        <img class="logo" src="./img/mind.png" alt="">
      </div>
      <div>
        <div class="searchbar">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Digite sua busca...">
          <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
        </div>
        <nav>
          <a class="link" href="#">Feminino</a>
          <a class="link" href="#">Masculino</a>
          <a class="link" href="#">Infantil</a>
        </nav>
      </div>
      <div>
        <i class="icones fa fa-bell"></i>
        <i class="icones fa fa-shopping-bag"></i>
        <i class="icones fa fa-heart"></i>
        <i class="icones fa fa-user-circle"></i>
      </div>
    </header>
    <main>
      <div class="container">
        <img class="bolso" src="./img/bolso.jpg" alt="">

        <img class="kel" src="./img/kel.jpg" alt="">

        <img class="sabri" src="./img/sabri.jpg" alt="">

        <img class="mirian" src="./img/mirian.jpg" alt="">

        <img class="yuri" src="./img/yuri.jpg" alt="">

        <img class="naro" src="./img/naro.jpg" alt="">

        <img class="deus" src="./img/deus.jpg" alt="">

        <img class="julio" src="./img/julio.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
    </main>
    <footer>

    </footer>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Em casos onde item terá mais de uma linha ou coluna, acredito que seja mais fácil utilizar a propriedade grid invés de flex.

Eu não consegui entender completamente como você quer deixar o layout do container, por isso encontrei duas opções.

OBS: deixei comentários no código sobre quais propriedades foram adicionadas, e quais foram retiradas.

**Opção1**

As fotos ficando separadas da página:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
   body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.app {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.app header {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 20vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background: rgb(194, 122, 239);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(194, 122, 239, 1) 15%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 93%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(194, 122, 239, 1) 15%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 93%);
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(194, 122, 239, 1) 15%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 93%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#c27aef", endColorstr="#ffffff", GradientType=1);
}


/* HEADER */

.app header div {
  width: 55%;
}


/* Div da esquerda */

.app header div:nth-child(1) {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  position: relative;
}


/* Div do centro */

.app header div:nth-child(2) {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-direction: column;
}


/* Div da direita */

.app header div:nth-child(3) {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.logo {
  width: 130px;
  margin-right: 40px;
}


/* SEARCHBAR */

div.searchbar {
  background-color: #fff;
  height: fit-content !important;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 50% !important;
  min-width: 300px;
}

div.searchbar input {
  outline: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0;
  width: 90%;
}


/* Nav bar */

a.link {
  margin-top: 10px;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 30px 10px;
}


/* Icones */

.icones {
  margin: 0 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

div.container {
  

  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  

/*PROPRIEDADE QUE FORAM RETIRADAS */
  /*
  position: absolute;  
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-direction: column; 
  */
  
  
/*PROPRIEDADE QUE FORAM ADICIONADAS */
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    "foto1 foto2"
    "foto3 foto4"   
    "foto5 foto6"
    "foto7 foto8"; 
  
}

.bolso {
  width: 130px;
  /*PROPRIEDADE QUE FOI ADICIONADA */
  grid-area: foto1;
}

.kel {
  width: 130px;
  /*PROPRIEDADE QUE FOI ADICIONADA */
  grid-area: foto2;
}

.julio {
  width: 130px;
  /*PROPRIEDADE QUE FOI ADICIONADA */
  grid-area: foto3;
}

.deus {
  width: 130px;
  /*PROPRIEDADE QUE FOI ADICIONADA */
  grid-area: foto4;
}

.sabri {
  width: 130px;
  /*PROPRIEDADE QUE FOI ADICIONADA */
  grid-area: foto5;
}

.yuri {
  width: 130px;
  /*PROPRIEDADE QUE FOI ADICIONADA */
  grid-area: foto6;
}

.mirian {
  width: 130px;
  /*PROPRIEDADE QUE FOI ADICIONADA */
  grid-area: foto7;
}

.naro {
  width: 130px;
  /*PROPRIEDADE QUE FOI ADICIONADA */
  grid-area: foto8;
}
```

**Opção 2**

As fotos ficando centralizadas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.app {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.app header {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 20vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background: rgb(194, 122, 239);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(194, 122, 239, 1) 15%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 93%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(194, 122, 239, 1) 15%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 93%);
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(194, 122, 239, 1) 15%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 93%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#c27aef", endColorstr="#ffffff", GradientType=1);
}


/* HEADER */

.app header div {
  width: 55%;
}


/* Div da esquerda */

.app header div:nth-child(1) {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  position: relative;
}


/* Div do centro */

.app header div:nth-child(2) {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-direction: column;
}


/* Div da direita */

.app header div:nth-child(3) {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.logo {
  width: 130px;
  margin-right: 40px;
}


/* SEARCHBAR */

div.searchbar {
  background-color: #fff;
  height: fit-content !important;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 50% !important;
  min-width: 300px;
}

div.searchbar input {
  outline: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0;
  width: 90%;
}


/* Nav bar */

a.link {
  margin-top: 10px;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 30px 10px;
}


/* Icones */

.icones {
  margin: 0 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

div.container {
  


  

/*PROPRIEDADE QUE FORAM RETIRADAS */
  /*
  position: absolute;  
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-direction: column; 

  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  */
  
  
/*PROPRIEDADE QUE FORAM ADICIONADAS */
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    "foto1 foto2"
    "foto3 foto4"   
    "foto5 foto6"
    "foto7 foto8"; 
  
}

.bolso {
  width: 130px;
  /*PROPRIEDADE QUE FOI ADICIONADA */
  grid-area: foto1;
}

.kel {
  width: 130px;
  /*PROPRIEDADE QUE FOI ADICIONADA */
  grid-area: foto2;
}

.julio {
  width: 130px;
  /*PROPRIEDADE QUE FOI ADICIONADA */
  grid-area: foto3;
}

.deus {
  width: 130px;
  /*PROPRIEDADE QUE FOI ADICIONADA */
  grid-area: foto4;
}

.sabri {
  width: 130px;
  /*PROPRIEDADE QUE FOI ADICIONADA */
  grid-area: foto5;
}

.yuri {
  width: 130px;
  /*PROPRIEDADE QUE FOI ADICIONADA */
  grid-area: foto6;
}

.mirian {
  width: 130px;
  /*PROPRIEDADE QUE FOI ADICIONADA */
  grid-area: foto7;
}

.naro {
  width: 130px;
  /*PROPRIEDADE QUE FOI ADICIONADA */
  grid-area: foto8;
}
```